# jquery synchronous execute

Tags: jquery, synchronous

Very Sorry for my english,i have a problem.

```
$("#MainPicture").attr("src", url);
CenterImg();
```

needs to be execute line 2 code  after line 1 code finished . it is asynchronous and i want the code excute by synchronous . Thanks All.

Question Details;
i want to move $("#MainPicture") in the center screen when picture loaded.like this.

```
$("#MainPicture").attr("src", url);
// new picture width,not old picture width
var PictureWidth=$("#MainPicture").width();
var ScreenWidth=$(window).width();
var ResultWidth=(ScreenWidth-PictureWidth)/2;
$("#MainPicture").css("left",ResultWidth);
```

in fact,in line 2 code,i alway get old picture width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#MainPicture").attr("src", url).one('load', CenterImg );

function CenterImg() {
    var PictureWidth = $("#MainPicture").width();
    var ScreenWidth = $(window).width();
    var ResultWidth = (ScreenWidth - PictureWidth) / 2;
    $("#MainPicture").css("left", ResultWidth);
}
```

This adds a `load` handler using the [`one()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method, which simply binds the handler, and unbinds it after the first time it executes.

The handler in this case is your `CenterImg()` function, so it will be invoked when the image is finished loading.

---

If there's a chance that the image is cached, and you still want the function to be invoked, you can do this:

```
$("#MainPicture").attr("src", url)
                 .one('load', CenterImg )
                 .filter(function() { return this.complete; })
                 .load();

function CenterImg() {
    var PictureWidth = $("#MainPicture").width();
    var ScreenWidth = $(window).width();
    var ResultWidth = (ScreenWidth - PictureWidth) / 2;
    $("#MainPicture").css("left", ResultWidth);
}
```

This way if the image is already loaded, `this.complete` will return `true`, and the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method will return a jQuery object with that image so you can manually invoke your `.load()` handler.

If the image has *not* yet finished loading, the `.filter()` will return `0` elements, and the manual `load()` will have no effect.

Comment: If the image is already in the cache, the load event will fire before you've attached your event handler.

Comment: @Zack Bloom: If the image is already in the cache, the load handler won't fire at all.

Comment: Yes it does, if you bind the event it before changing the src.

Comment: +1 for the cache trick. There seems to be some difference in opinion about image load being fired when image is loaded from cache. Does anyone have any hard evidence of which is true?

Comment: @Zack Bloom: [Here's your code](http://jsfiddle.net/NAar7/). Indeed, it does seem to invoke the handler even though the image is presumably cached. [Here's my code](http://jsfiddle.net/NAar7/1/), and it also invokes the handler. *(The handler is added after a 3 second timeout to give the original image time to load.)*

Comment: @Mrchief: Check out the 2 examples in the comment above. They both change an image to one that is cached, and they both seem to work. This does surprise me a bit.

Comment: [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/NAar7/2/) to the example using my code. It adds a `console.log()` between the `.attr()` and the `.load()` to show that the `.complete` property is indeed `true`. Adding the handler after it, it is still invoked. jQuery must do its own `.complete` test, and invoke the handler if it is added when `.complete` is already `true`.

Comment: [Decided to try it with native methods.](http://jsfiddle.net/NAar7/3/) Still works (in Chrome anyway) to attach the handler after changing the `.src` to an already loaded image. That entirely surprises me. I'm certain I've come across issues with cached images not invoking load handlers. Anyway, I'm talking to myself at this point. :)

Comment: thanks @patrick dw and Zack Bloom, i try your code,but show "Loaded" before #MainPicture src change into Google Logo,i want to move img($("#MainPicture").css("left","100px")) when img loaded finished

Comment: @Magiczmi: It works for me. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/NAar7/6/) using your updated code. I also updated my answer. If it doesn't work, let me know what browser you're using.

Comment: @patrick dw it can work using firefox,but doesn't work using ie8.i am using ie8.you can work in ie8?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want it to be synchronous, you want to be able to run your function at the *right* asynchronous point.

```
$("#MainPicture").load(CenterImg).attr("src", url);
```