# hide() function does not hide the image when is needed

Tags: jquery, hide

```
<ul id="ulBack">
   <li><img data-src="coffee/01.jpg" class="place"></li>
   <li><img data-src="coffee/02.jpg" class="place"></li>
   <li><img data-src="coffee/03.jpg" class="place"></li>   
</ul>



 $('#btnNext').click(function () {
        $('#slide').hide();
        if (n < xlen) {n+=1;}
        else {n=0};
        change();
        border();
    });

function change(){
    var goImg = $('#ulBack img' + ':eq(' + n +')').attr('data-src');
    $('#slide').attr('src', goImg);
};
```

At the end of `border()` function I have:

```
$('#slide').show();
```

So, I want firstly hide the slide, then do all other things, and finally - show the slide.

But, it is evident that after clicking next button, program waits something, probably executes the rest of code, and then, at the end, just quickly hides and shows the slide, which is not the intention.

You can see [here](http://zokam.22web.org/coffee.php)

Comment: Your code is rather simple, and executes within milliseconds, so you'll never see the hide/show. What you're seeing is the new image loading, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this like so :

```
function change(){
    var goImg = $('#ulBack img' + ':eq(' + n +')').attr('data-src');
    $('#slide').one('load', function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).attr('src', goImg).each(function() {
        if(this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
}

function border() {
    if([0,1,2,3,4,10,33,37].indexOf(n) != -1){
        $('#slide').css('border', 'none');
    } else {
        $('#slide').css('border', 'medium ridge #6c9');
    }
}
```

Comment: adeneo, I will try, although I don't understand you code. Thanks

Comment: .one('load', function(){}) add a callback that will only work ONCE on the "load" event. So everytime you change the source, add it. This will ensure the image will appear again everytime the changed image is loaded

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it: the longest part of your treatment is a request to get the new image I think, and for that you use a jQuery Ajax query isn't it ?

I think your Ajax query is **asynchronous**, and thus the show() is called on the old picture, before the new picture is loaded. This gives you the feeling the picture is never hidden. To solve it, make your ajax request synchronous:

```
$.ajax({
  ...,
  async: false
})
```

Comment: You should probably post that again.

Comment: Ricola3D, you properly described the problem, but i don't use ajax. I use jquery to change the img src attribute.

Comment: If you don't use AJAX, then the description of the problem isn't too accurate :)

Comment: Ok. Could you show us the code used to change the src and reload it please ? So we can see how to force jQuery to make it synchronously ? Anyway add a console.log("foo"); at the moment you show, open your web browser console and look if "foo" appears before or after the image is loaded (GET request with status 200). This will tell us if my analysis is near the true issue :)

Comment: I read something interesting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048157/jquery-synchronous-execute. You can use one() to add a callback that will work only once on the "load" event. In this callback you can put all the treatements to do once the image is loaded (e.g. the show() call )

Comment: Who is upvoting these answers? Ajax for image loading, setting **asynchronous** function to synchronous behaviour etc ?

Comment: Ricola3D, I updated the post. You can see the actual code for changing img src

Comment: See my last comment and adeneo's answer for the solution. I think the one("load", ...) should solve your issue !

Answer (score 0):

This might help .. not sure if this is what you want

```
  $('#slide').hide();
        if (n < xlen) {n+=1;}
        else {n=0};
        change();
        border();
    setTimeout(function() { $("#slide").show(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: So hide the image, then wait five seconds, and hide the image. Makes sense, at least it did to whoever upvoted it ?

Comment: It is very not an elegant way to solve that issue. If somebody has a wooden connection, he won't see the picture hide itself.

Comment: So now we're waiting five seconds, and then show the image, great UX.

Comment: @adeneo I guess this is a tipo, the image is to be shown after 5s